# Single executable file created by py2exe not working

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, pyqt4, anaconda, py2exe

I've created a Python app using Pyqt4 to open up a dialog and do some image processing using opencv2.  The app is working fine when executing the script as:

python script.py

To create a single executable file for the script, I'm using py2exe with bundle_files = 1 option. It is creating a single exe file but when clicking the file, a console appears stays for few seconds and a pop-up appears saying program has stopped responding.

I'm working on Windows with anaconda. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Py2exe generates a logfile.txt in the same folder you first-time execute the generated **.exe**.
Check this logfile to debug.

Most of the time you need to exclude some dll`s and include at least **sip**-module;

In your setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import shutil, py2exe

opts = {'py2exe': {'compressed': True, "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll"], "includes" : ["sip"]}}

setup(console=[{"script" : "main.py"}], options=opts)
shutil.rmtree('build', ignore_errors=True)           #Remove the build folder
```

Personally I did not encounter the need to include PyQt4 modules for compilation..

And btw be glad that python is an interpreted language, otherwise you`ll have to worry about linking to libraries on every build (like in cpp.., which is annoying)

Greets Dr Cobra

Comment: Where did you find all that? Do they work for you? Ig yes, what PY version do you use?